# Why does this markdown preview differently?

Tags: support, markdown-rendering, markdown-preview

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15228515/4233593). When published, the markdown does not render the same way it does in preview for edit mode. The numbered list does not continue when published, but appears to continue in preview. Moreover, the OP actually typed `2`, but it still rendered as `1` which is puzzling.

---

## Published

---

[image: published markdown rendered]

---

## Editor Preview

---

[image: preview editor markdown rendered]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When that post was created, our Markdown parser ignored the numbers and always started new lists at 1. That has since changed, but the post has never been re-rendered to reflect that change, so it is still showing a cached copy of how it was rendered *at the time it was posted*.

If you simply make some completely frivolous change so that the system caches a new rendered copy, it will update to display the same as the preview.

Comment: Is there any process to automatically re-render cached markdown when the parser changes?  I mean, will this eventually get cleaned up on its own, or does this require someone to make an intentional (hopefully non-frivolous) edit to render the proper results?

Comment: @Michael No, everything is left alone because there's no way to determine which posts would actually be affected by a change. "Re-caching" is literally running a process which runs every single post on the network through the parser again and store the new ouput. Far easier to just let someone update it when they see it.